# Can I use OCS 2007 without Certificates?

Tags: certificate, ms-office-communicator

Quick question

Everyone using OCS2007 will be internal.  We have no need for certificates.  Is there a setting I can use to disable Certificates?

Everything was working fine in Communicator right up until the time I wanted to add another SIP domain.  Now I am having trouble with the certificates for the secondary SIP domain.

How can I disable using Certs altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around I think I found it.  Does't work with automatic login, but it works.

In Communicator Client, goto Tools->Options.  Fill in the manual details and use TCP

In Office Communicator Server 2007 Settings, right click on your pool->Properties->Front End
Click the add button.  Select TCP from the drop down.

That should work

Comment: Have you got internal DNS SRV entries for _sipinternal._tcp.company.com and _sip._tcp.company.com to point to your OCS server? If not that might be enough to get it to work, and if you have then removing the TLS related OCS SRV entries might help.

Comment: Yes, I have the following SRV entries in place for the second SIP (@company.com), but the only one that works still is @company.local

sip.company.com (A record)
_sipinternaltls._tcp.company.com (SRV and A)

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall the specifics for OCS 2007, but be aware that OCS 2007 R2 will not start up without a default outbound certificate configured, even if there is only one server and TLS is not needed for client connections. You *might* be able to create a self-signed certificate and install that on a single server, but then you are in untested (and hence unsupported) territory.

Comment: I have configured the server as a Certificate Authority which generated the certificate, so I believe it is self-signed.
So yes, there is a certificate set up now, but it is only working for sip@company.local, but TLS does not work on sip@company.com, so I have to use TCP